# Getting manifest merger failed after adding cardview dependency

Tags: android-studio, cardview

I want to use cardview in my app, so I added cardview dependency. But got error manifest merger failed.
I added following dependency and got following error:

Can anyone help?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the same version for com.android.support libraries. You are using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1` for appcompat and `com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha` for cardview. Both the libraries are support libraries. It is recommended to use the same version for support libraries because mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes. Inn your case you can use

```
com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0
```

and

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0
```

it will build without errors.

You can see both libraries have same versions. New libraries will come in the future. So keep in mind you use the same version.